# how to run mpi on cluster?

Tags: c++, mpi, cluster-computing

my_hostfile.txt is :

> ```
> node1 slots=12 max-slots=12
> node2 slots=12 max-slots=12
> node3 slots=12 max-slots=12
> node4 slots=12 max-slots=12
> ```

for run the program, I used this command:

```
mpirun --hostfile my_hostfile.txt -pernode -n 48 ./run_mpi 13-4 -l 13 -d 4
```

result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open RTE detected a parse error in the hostfile:
    my_hostfile.txt
It occured on line number 1 on token 1.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[node4:30641] [0,0,0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file rmgr_urm.c at line 358
[node4:30641] mpirun: spawn failed with errno=-1
```

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure the hostfile is ASCII and not something like 2-byte Unicode. Or there might be an UTF-8 BOM at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I edit the hostfile in Windows by VSCode and the end of line is by default `CRLF`. By switching to `LF` the problem is gone.